# How do I change the default Internet Explorer fonts?

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

When Internet Explorer goes to use a fixed-width font, I want to override the default (Consolas or Courrier New, depending on Windows version) with my own font. Basically, whenever someone uses `<tt>` tags or asks for the `fixed` font. (I'd like to replace these with Anonymous Pro)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the "Plain text font" under Tools > Internet Options > General > Fonts is the one you need to change.

Update:

To override a font defined by the web page you are viewing, create a CSS file and in it put:

```
tt, pre, code { font-family: "Anonymous Pro" !important; }
```

Then under Tools > Internet Options > General > Accessibility, select "Format documents using my style sheet", and provide the location of the CSS file you created above.

Comment: That changes the font for plain text, yes. I don't think it affects anything else though.

Comment: Just confirmed it also changes the <tt> tag contents.

Comment: Still shows up as Consolas for me. I don't think this setting changes it because the default here is Courier New -- but the default fixed-width font in IE is Consolas, not Courier New.

Comment: Are you using IE9? I am, and I definitely see the changes. In fact, I can see them even before I hit 'OK' on the Internet Options page.

Comment: @Soumya92: Yes, I'm using IE 9.

Comment: Do you have a sample page? As you can see here: http://i.imgur.com/PJpoe.png my fonts are changing fine.

Comment: Yes, this one. `The text in here is still Consolas on my box.`.

Comment: Aha. The font here is defined by SuperUser. See updated answer.

Comment: See my new screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/AGiqb.png

Answer (score 2):

- Go to Internet Option >> Accessibility (I hope you know where to access Internet Option)
- Check below option

> ignore font styles specified on webpages

or whichever you prefer.

- Go to Internet Option >> Font >> Select desired font. >> ok
  Now you can see that font on the web page is changed....